# Unity interstitial ads not working in activity but working in fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, ads

I have implemented interstitial ads in fragment of my app , it was working there, this is the code which i used:

```
    if (UnityAds.isReady (constants.interstitial)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "showAd: ad ready and showing...")
        UnityAds.show (activity, constants.interstitial)
    }
```

[image]

but when i am using this same code in my activity in my app, interstitial ads are not working at all

[image]

my code is in kotlin

where is the mistake?

Comment: The ads are probably not ready when called

Comment: no i am testing in test ads (test ads are enabled), ads are working but not coming in activity but coming in fragments

Comment: Where do you call the `UnityAds.initialize()` method?

Comment: i have created a common class where i had written for calling it for other activities

Comment: I believe the problem may be that when the activity starts, the ads are not ready to show and `UnityAds.isReady()` probably returns `false`

Comment: so can u tell me how to solve it?

Comment: More details are required. Could you show exactly where is the initialization (is it before calling `UnityAds.isReady()`)?
Is the activity the first one to launch? Is the `Fragment` the first one?
Please, show the relevant code.

Comment: Please don't show code as image but as text